# Emit a second variable from Vue component to parent (vue / inertiajs)

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

I have the following component, I would like to emit a second value **isDeleted** to the parent:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <button class="btn my-auto inset-y-0 ml-1 mr-3"
      :class="isDeleted ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-secondary'"
      @click="switchMode"
    >
      <Icon name="Trash" class="w-4 h-4" />
    </button>

    <div class="w-56 relative text-slate-500 mr-2">
      <input
        id="tabulator-html-filter-value"
        name="search"
        type="text"
        autocomplete="off"
        class="form-control w-56 box pr-10"
        aria-label="default input example"
        :value="modelValue"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
        placeholder="Search..."
      />
      <Icon name="Search" class="w-4 h-4 absolute my-auto inset-y-0 mr-3 right-0"/>
    </div>
    <button
      id="tabulator-html-filter-reset"
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-secondary w-full sm:w-16 mt-2 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-1"
      @click="$emit('reset')"
    >
      Reset
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Dropdown from '@/components/Dropdown/Dropdown'
import Icon from '@/components/Icons/Icons'

export default {
  components: {
    Dropdown,
    Icon
  },
  props: {
    modelValue: String,
    maxWidth: {
      type: Number,
      default: 300,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isDeleted: null,
    }
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue', 'reset'],
  methods: {
    switchMode() {
      this.isDeleted = this.isDeleted ? null : 'only';
      console.log('1'+ this.isDeleted);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The parent has the following code:

```
        <search-filter v-model="form.search" class="mr-4 w-full max-w-md" @reset="reset" />
```

I tried following this example: https://dev.to/codybontecou/vuejs-custom-event-emit-multiple-values-221b to add emit the second value **isDeleted** without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In child

```html
<button
    id="tabulator-html-filter-reset"
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-secondary w-full sm:w-16 mt-2 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-1"
    @click="$emit('reset', isDeleted /* <---- Pass your value */)"
>
```

In parent

```html
<search-filter
    v-model="form.search"
    class="mr-4 w-full max-w-md"
    @reset="reset($event /* <---- Here got your value */)"
/>
```

```js
const reset = (isDeleted) =>
{
    console.log(isDeleted)
}
```